# Custom registration with Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I have two different user types: teachers and students. Teachers register accounts in registration form in website but student registration is provided by a windows application. So I must provide an API to this application. Default Laravel auth is enough for teacher registration but can I use same AuthController for API registration? I don't need a view or redirect to website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options actually

1. create a method on your auth controller and apply a middleware to the controller method which would only be available for api calls so a student doesnt create himself/herself as a teacher, you can read more about same here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware
2. which I would suggest is to create another auth controller for your api calls that only serves for creating student accounts that way its clean, easier to manage and concept of separation of concerns is put into practice.

Comment: Thank you. I chosed second option and it worked for me.